# How to name 1000 textbox programmatically inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have 1000 text boxes. I'm trying to put name for all the 1000 text boxes programmatically in 5 minutes using string replace function or any method.

```
<html>
<form id="exp">
<input type="text" value="A1">
<input type="text" value="A2">
<input type="text" value="A3">
.
.
.
<input type="text" value="A1000">
</form>
</html>
```

```html
var element = document.getElementById("exp");
var html = element.outerHTML;
html = html.replace("input type="text"","input type="text" name="name"");
```

I would like to show my expected result as 'var html' as follows

```
<html>
<form id="exp">
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="A1">
<input type="text" name="textbox2" value="A2">
<input type="text" name="textbox3" value="A3">
.
.
.
<input type="text" name="textbox1000" value="A1000">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Unclear why you would need to do this with angular.... Why are they being outputted like that in the first place? Shouldn't angular be setting the name?

Comment: `html.replace('input type="text"','input type="text" name="name"')` Don't use `"` for a String when you have `"` IN the String, or escape the `"` with \

Comment: what you can do, if you have to put different names for 1000 text boxes in 5 minutes

Comment: Also, what is your result when you run the code? Where does the problem occur?

Comment: Hi All I want a form with 1000 and more fields there i just want to put different names to them.

Comment: Why don't you let Angular do that...

Comment: I have to save entire form with data as a string to db in angular @ritag And can you answer this question in angular.

Comment: How are you creating the form?

Comment: there are various toots to generate form controls @ritaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use document.getElementsByTagName

```
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
    inputs[i].name = "text" + (i + 1);
```

Comment: What if there were less than 1000 inputs in the dom? Your code would break. Should loop over the length.

Answer (score 2):

Matching html with a regular expression is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/). Not sure why you would be doing it with a regular expression. Select the elements and set it in a loop.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#exp input").forEach(function (inp, index) {
  inp.name = 'textbox' + (index + 1);
  // inp.name = `textbox${index + 1}`;
})
```

```html
<form id="exp">
  <input type="text" value="A1">
  <input type="text" value="A2">
  <input type="text" value="A3">
</form>
```